# JMeter - Write requests and responses to a file

Tags: jmeter

I need to write the responses and requests for all samplers in my threads.
I have a "View Results Tree" under my entire tests sets (as long with one I have inside every thread), and I know the option for "write results to file" I have in the results tree. The problem is that it writes the logs only when all tests has finished running.
Is there a way to write the responses and requests to a file without waiting for everything to finish running?

Answer (score 4):

You can amend JMeter configuration so it will store request and response details into its .jtl results file during test execution.

1. Add the following lines to *user.properties* file (it's located under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
   ```
2. Start JMeter in [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) as

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/testresults.jtl
   ```
3. Monitor `testresults.jtl` in the real time with your favourite tool

Remember that saving request and response details causes massive disk IO and may have negative impact on JMeter performance hence your test results might be not reliable.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on what you can control with the help of different JMeter Properties.